# g.fillRect in Eclipse is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I am watching a tutorial from this guy :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwu4DAoac-I

...And now I have to use the

g.fillRect(..,.., getWidtch(), getHeight());

Code.

But Eclipse doesnt have that so I cannot continue programming. That has to be in some package.

And if I wanted to download all packages with SHIFT, CTRL, O

Eclipse doesnt do anything.

What is the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Preferably if you show your code we can help better, but have you tried to import the Graphics class from awt?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

1. Try ctrl-shift-O in that order instead.
2. Hover your mouse over `g.fillRect`. There should be an option to import it.
3. At the top of the file, type `import java.awt.Graphics`